# Reverse dictionary possible here?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I used a dictionary to show all the skins that a champ has. Is it possible to use this same list to show all the champs that have a certain skin in common? For Example, if katarina and ekko both had 'Firelight' as skins, I could input 'firelight' and the return would be 'ekko, katarina'.

```
ekko_skins = ['Firelight', 'Pulsefire', 'True Damage', 'Sandstorm', 'Academy', 'Project: Ekko', 'Start Gardian']
kat_skins = ['Mercenary', 'Battle Academia', 'Blood Moon', 'Battle Queen', 'High Noon', 'Red Card', 'Bilgewater', 'Kitty Cat', 'Slay Belle', 'Death Sworn']

champ_skin_dict = {'ekko': [ekko_skins], 'katarina': [kat_skins]}

while True:
    user_champ = input('Champion: ').lower()
    print(champ_skin_dict[user_champ])
    continue
```

Comment: Have a look at `set.intersection` for commonalities between lists.

Comment: Is there any reason why the skins lists are wrapped in another list inside the skin dictionary?

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
ekko_skins = ['Firelight', 'Pulsefire', 'True Damage', 'Sandstorm', 'Academy', 'Project: Ekko', 'Start Gardian', 'Some skin in common']
kat_skins = ['Mercenary', 'Battle Academia', 'Blood Moon', 'Battle Queen', 'High Noon', 'Red Card', 'Bilgewater', 'Kitty Cat', 'Slay Belle', 'Death Sworn', 'Some skin in common']

champ_skin_dict = {'ekko': ekko_skins, 'katarina': kat_skins}

while True:
    user_skin = input('Skin: ').lower()
    print(', '.join([j for j in champ_skin_dict.keys() if user_skin in [i.lower() for i in champ_skin_dict[j]]]))
    should_continue = input('Would you like to input another skin? y/n ').lower()
    if should_continue == 'n':
      break
```

Output:

```
Skin: Pulsefire
ekko
Would you like to input another skin? y/n y
Skin: Some skin in common
ekko, katarina
Would you like to input another skin? y/n n
```

Every time the user inputs a skin, this just iterates through the dictionary and only returns the keys with the user inputed skin in them. The `.join` is used to put a comma in between every champion with the skin.

Also for some reason when you created the dictionary like so:

```
{'ekko': [ekko_skins], 'katarina': [kat_skins]}
```

You put the `list` of skins in square brackets which would make the 1 dimensional list look like this:

```
[['some list item', 'another list item']]
```

To avoid this just make the dictionary like I did, like this:

```
{'ekko': ekko_skins, 'katarina': kat_skins}
```

Multi dimensional lists (or arrays/matrixes/tensors as they are more commonly called. They do have differences though, see this [article](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/differences-between-a-matrix-and-a-tensor/)) are used to represent multidimensional data like that stored in a `dict`.

Comment: This statement “Multi dimensional lists (or arrays/matrixes/tensors as they are more commonly called) are used to represent multidimensional data like that stored in a dict.” is highly inaccurate, on multiple counts.  These structures are *not* terms to be used interchangeably.

Comment: I understand this, I was just explaining it simply, as their structure is basically the same but they do have some differences based on how they function

Comment: @S3DEV I edited my post to include a link to an article explaining the differences between a matrix and a tensor. Sorry that my post was misleading, I just wanted to include something about that but didn't want to write a whole article on it, thus leading to my misleading statement.

Comment: @S3DEV I edited my post to include a link to an article explaining the differences between a matrix and a tensor. Sorry that my post was misleading, I just wanted to include something about that but didn't want to write a whole article on it, thus leading to my misleading statement.